# Is there a nonexhaustive proof that the maximum number of spanning trees in a connected $10$-vertex $3$-regular graph is $2000$?

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof, trees

It is well-known that the number of spanning trees in the Petersen graph is $2000$. The Petersen graph, in fact, has the most spanning trees out of all connected $10$-vertex $3$-regular (a.k.a. cubic) graphs. I believe this was first shown by Valdes in a 1991 conference paper. However, the proof is simply an exhaustive proof where the number of spanning trees in each of the $19$ connected $10$-vertex $3$-regular graphs is checked manually.

My question is the following:

> Is there a nonexhaustive proof that the maximum number of spanning trees in a connected $10$-vertex $3$-regular graph is $2000$?

Comment: One plausible plan of attack: give an upper bound (less than $2000$) on the number of spanning trees of a $10$-vertex Hamiltonian cubic graph. This gives us what we want because the Petersen graph is the only $10$-vertex connected cubic graph that's not Hamiltonian. However, we can't give away too much in the upper bound since the runner-up has $1920$ spanning trees.

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks for the response! I don't believe your "plan of attack" will ultimately change the style of proof; we will still have to manually check which of the $10$-vertex cubic graphs are Hamiltonian. Also, I disagree with your statement that "the Petersen graph is the only $10$-vertex connected cubic graph that's not Hamiltonian." Graph #1 in http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/markus/REGGRAPHS/10_3_3.html (which is not the Petersen graph) has a cut-edge and hence is not Hamiltonian.

Comment: Okay, I was forgetting about that one, but it's easy to show that a $10$-vertex cubic graph with a cut-edge can't have too many spanning trees.

Comment: Anyway, it's certainly possible to prove upper bounds on the number of spanning trees in a $10$-vertex Hamiltonian cubic graph without manually checking any cases. I can prove an upper bound of $3205$. It's just hard to make the bounds tight enough.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a starting point for an argument; if there is a non-exhaustive proof, maybe it can be obtained by improving these bounds. I don't mean this as a final answer, but it's a proof of concept that a non-exhaustive proof could possibly exist, and what it could look like.

**Lemma.** If a $10$-vertex cubic graph is Hamiltonian, it has at most $3205$ spanning trees.

**Proof.** Actually, all we need is that the graph as a $3$-edge-coloring. If there is a Hamiltonian cycle, we can color its edges alternately red and blue, and then color the leftover matching green.

We count the number of spanning trees that use $0$, $1$, or $2$ red edges.

- If $0$ red edges are used, then there are at most $\binom{10}{9}=10$ trees, since we need to pick $9$ of the remaining edges.
- If $1$ red edge is used, then the blue and green edges form two paths of lengths $a,b$ (with $a+b=10$) from one endpoint of the red edge to the other, or from an endpoint back to itself. Either way, one edge from each path must be deleted, for at most $ab \le 25$ trees.
- If $2$ red edges are used, then the blue and green paths form four paths of length $a,b,c,d$ with $a+b+c+d=10$ that start and end at one of the chosen red edges. We must delete an edge from all but one of the paths to get a tree, so there are at most $abc+abd+acd+bcd$ trees. This is maximized when $a,b,c,d = 2,2,3,3$ in some order, when we get an upper bound of $60$.

Altogether there are at most $\binom 50 \cdot 10 + \binom51 \cdot 25 + \binom 52 \cdot 60 = 735$ such trees. There are also at most $735$ trees that use at most $2$ blue edges, and at most $735$ trees that use at most $2$ green edges. Finally, there are at most $\binom 53^3 = 1000$ trees that use $3$ edges of each color. The total is $3 \cdot 735 + 1000 = 3205$. $\square$

(Note that $735$ is close to the truth; some cubic graphs have $\approx 600$ graphs of this type, in some edge-colorings. On the other hand, $1000$ is a bad overestimate.)

---

If we could get this bound from $3205$ down to less than $2000$, we'd be done.

- If a $10$-vertex cubic graph has a bridge, then it connects two $5$-vertex pieces with $7$ edges each. (The number of vertices in each piece must be odd by degree counts, and $3$ vertices is too small to have any vertices of degre $3$.) A spanning tree must take the bridge and $4$ edges from each piece, and there are $\binom 74^2 = 1225$ ways to do that, some of which won't even make trees.
- The Petersen graph is the unique smallest bridgeless cubic graph that's not Hamiltonian. (This is also something we can prove without an exhaustive search.)